# In the Joule-Thomson experiment, how is $T_1-T_2$ determined?

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]

I figured out that $H = U +pV$ is constant in this adiabatic condition. I am confused about the expression "$T_1-T_2$ is determined in this condition".

I don't think it's an ideal gas, so $\delta(H) \neq C_p \delta(T)$, which makes $\delta(T) \neq 0$.

Should I approach with $\delta(H) = \delta(U +pV)$ when $\delta(H) =0$, so $\delta(U + pV) =0$, and since the process is adiabatic.

$$\delta(U) = -\mathcal L = p_1V_1 -p_2V_2$$ But still it is not an ideal gas, we cannot say

$$\delta(U) = C_v \delta(T)$$

Where should I get $T_1 - T_2$, is it just implicit?

Comment: Are you saying that you are dealing with a real gas, not an ideal gas, and you are supposed to find the equation for the temperature change?

Comment: Are you familiar with the following equation for a real gas:  $$dH=C_pdT+\left[V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]dP$$